# Send different pieces of PHP form data to different email addresses on 1 submit button

Tags: php, forms, email

Is there a way to send different pieces of data from a PHP form to different email recipients using 1 submit button? 
For instance, when a user clicks 'SUBMIT', I want to send ONLY the user's name, address, email address, and phone number to company email address "A", and send the user's complaint/message and model information to company email address 'B'.
**I'm new to PHP and have tried researching the issue, but I may be using the wrong terminology. (So any help would be appreciated THERE too.)
THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: call mail() twice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. you should use `mail` function for this purpose. You have an action parameter in your html form like this:

```
<form name="user_data" action="submit.php" method="post">

    // form fields here ...

</form>
```

and in your `submit.php` after sanitizing, validating and processing form data you will have:

```
mail("someone@example1.com","Subject1",$msg1);
mail("someotherone@example2.com","Subject2",$msg2);
```

where `$msg1` and `$msg2` are composed messages, containing any parts you need.